# AWS SSE not getting set?

Tags: java, angularjs, amazon-web-services

We are working on an upload process that gets a presigned url from the server to use for uploading files to our s3 bucket. Our request is being built like so

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest gpur = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, file);
gpur.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
gpur.setExpiration(expiration);
//gpur.setSSEAlgorithm(SSEAlgorithm.getDefault().getAlgorithm());
url = client.generatePresignedUrl(gpur);
```

and being consumed like so

```
$http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: gpur url,
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    uploadEventHandlers: {progress: function(progress) {
        file.uploadProgress = Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100);
    }},
    data: file,
})
```

which works great. The file gets moved to the bucket no problem. However, when we add `gpur.setSEEAlgorithm(SSEAlgorithm.getDefault().getAlgorithm())` back in, we get a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error. What we don't understand about the error is that in the `<CanonicalRequest>` tags, the value of `x-amz-server-side-encryption` is blank.

Is there something obvious we're missing here?

EDIT: After a bit of researching I found a similar question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114544/amazon-s3-specifying-sse-s3-with-pre-signed-urls-usingapex

I added

```
headers:{
    'X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption': 'AES256',
},
```

to the request and it works, although it seems to be case sensitive.

Comment: Would you be able to add your edit as an answer to your question for future readers? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my edit as an answer. :)

After a bit of researching I found a similar question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114544/amazon-s3-specifying-sse-s3-with-pre-signed-urls-usingapex

I added

headers:{
    'X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption': 'AES256',
},
to the request and it works, although it seems to be case sensitive